# Program for creating a cylinder given its axis, center and radius?

Tags: cad, geometry, computer-aided-design

I have data with the following normalized values:

Unit vector for cylinder axis:
-0.00270666, -0.01226211,  0.9999212

Normalized coordinates for cylinder center
0.01412114, 0.01074875, 0.00017004

Normalized cylinder radius
0.12903491

Is there any program I can use to display a cylinder with the following parameters? I know of programs like OpenSCAD that accept height and radius for a cylinder which can them be translated,rotated, etc. but I'm not sure how to use the unit vector of the axis to get the height (I assume for rotation I can use trignometric functions to derive the angle of the cylinder).

Thanks

Comment: None of that data gives you height information.  A unit vector is just that -- a vector that's one unit long, and thus only indicates direction.  So you know where it is, where it's pointing, and how big around it is, but that's it.

Comment: The height is 1 unit, if the axis is a unit vector...?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift Thats what I thought based on what was given, but I wasn't entirely sure. Since all the given parameters are normalized I guess I have to make assumptions about the true dimensions. Just wasn't sure if the axis vector could be used to find the height if it wasn't a unit vector.

Comment: I don't know the source of your information/vectors. It seems odd to define the height by the length of the vector, but that's what your question implied...